# flutter: when press phone return button, how to close both keyboard and page

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My page is like this:

when press return button on phone, only keyboard closes, while i have to press return button again to let background page close.

so when press return button, how to close both keyboard and page the same time?

Comment: emmmm...seems i failed to upload the picture.

Comment: the example picture is here:  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOY0s.png)

Comment: What "background page" are you talking about? Do you mean you want to *navigate* to another widget/screen?

Comment: I mean the page which keyboard is in. see this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOY0s.png)